# Axon Framework - How to implement Upstream - Downstream context design

Tags: axon

[image]Using Axon how to implemnt upstream - downstream DDD between domain and subdomain.

How we can make order agrigate listen to shipping sub domain events.

https://axoniq.io/blog-overview/bounded-contexts-with-axon

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is with Saga, similar to this: https://github.com/idugalic/digital-restaurant/blob/master/drestaurant-libs/drestaurant-order/src/main/kotlin/com/drestaurant/order/domain/OrderSaga.kt#L104

The long answer is:
Both services expose messaging API (commands you can send to, queries you can send to, events you can subscribe to). Order service depends on the Shipping service in this case. Both services implement sub-domain models (`Order` is not a whole domain, it can be a `core / more important` sub-domain maybe). Order domain is responsible for creating the `order` and validating this order in the process. Shipping is responsible for delivering the order and they call it Shipping there. In the Shipping context we are not interested in details of order and its content, we are interested in delivery address mostly.

The order saga I have mentioned in the previous section can handle `com.drestaurant.courier.domain.api.CourierOrderDeliveredEvent` event from the `shipping/courier` service and invoke a command on the Order service to update the state of the Order aggregate. It is important to note that we share messages as classes in the JAR file within this example. You should consider sharing/documenting only the schema of messages (for example JSON), and have copy of this API classes in depending services (no dependencies on the common API modules/jars of other services). That way you rely on the serialization of the messages, and you will have freedom to have slightly different copies of this messages/classes in depending services (e.g. you do not have to deserialize all the attributes of the message on the other side - you can choose). This will enable more independent deployment of your services, as they do not share any modules/jars what so ever.

I have to admit that is not always easy to discuss concepts from DDD, and they are always context related. Nevertheless, I hope this answer will put more light on the questions you have. Fill free to discuss this topic further.

Best,
Ivan

Comment: Understood, saga is the answer. However what if these domain - sub domain are to be deployed separately. For instance, if requirement is to implement and deploy order and shipment as two micro services, still they need to listen to dependant events.

Comment: Yes. If requirement is to implement and deploy order and shipment as two micro services, still they need to listen to dependant events! Axon server can distribute these events (commands and queries as well)

Comment: Did POC on distributed saga with spring boot applications for order & shipment. Implemented ShipmentSaga. Getting below exception -`WARN 13472 --- [nd-processor]-0] o.a.c.gateway.DefaultCommandGateway      : Command 'com.techm.bm.api.cmd.RegisterShipmentForOrderPreparedCmd' resulted in org.axonframework.eventsourcing.IncompatibleAggregateException(Aggregate identifier must be non-null after applying an event. Make sure the aggregate identifier is initialized at the latest when handling the creation event.)` Pls suggest what is wrong with code - https://gitlab.com/bm-cqrs/axon-kafka-distrbuted

Comment: I have provided a MR on your repo: https://gitlab.com/bm-cqrs/axon-kafka-distrbuted/merge_requests/1/commits

With this `improvements ` I was able to run your application/s successfully.